# How to change font and table size using <style type="text/css"> rmarkdown

Tags: css, html-table, r-markdown

I need some help setting up table cell sizes on rmakrdown. I added the following but it didn't do anything to the tables in the document:

```
<style type="text/css">
  }
td {  /* Table  */
  font-size: 12px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-width:3px
}
</style>
```

My tables are just too big. I thought the problem was due to font size so I changed it, but it didn't do anything to the table size.

[image]

Comment: When you use the tags <style> you don't need to include "type="text/css"", and post some of your code so that we can help you, testing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style type="text/css">
  } // this can't be here
td {  /* Table  */
  font-size: 12px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-width:3px
}
</style>
```

change it to this:

```
<style>
    th, td { 
      font-size: 12px;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-width:3px
    }
    </style>
```

Try it like this.. you had a `}` in your code that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Hi! Thank you -- it worked a bit, changed the font size in the table but didn't for the headers?

Comment: @song0089 table header data is usually in a `<th>` tag not a `<td>`, so just add `th` to your css selector. i.e. `td, th { }`

Comment: the "td" only affects the standard cells, the one's below the th cells. If you want it to have the same effect in the th too, check the updated answer above.

Comment: Thank you. I realized that it still doesn't shrink the table size, the margins between the text and the cell border is too wide. Is there something I should add more other than padder = 0px?

Comment: I also tried adding `width=100` but it did not shrink the cell size....

Answer (score 0):

may be your `body {}` style has default `font-size` set to that size, because adding style to `TD` changed the style of `TD` but not the other elements.